# List returning duplicate values while iterating in Java

Tags: java, list, jackson

Below program is iterating completely same values even though parsing is correct from JsonNode-

```
package com.test.testing;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KeyValue;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LoopCheck  {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String jsonValue = "{\"id\":\"247\",\"effective_date\":\"2020-06-21T23:30:00Z\",\"code_portions\":[{\"portion_code\":\"123\",\"portion_name\":\"Test1\"},{\"portion_code\":\"1234\",\"portion_name\":\"Test2\"}]}";
        ObjectMapper objectNode = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode value = objectNode.readTree(jsonValue);
        jsonLoopFunc("abc",value);

        }


    public static void jsonLoopFunc(String key, JsonNode value) throws IOException {
        List<KeyValue<String, JsonNode>> recordsList = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectMapper objectNode = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode portionValue = objectNode.readValue(String.valueOf(value), JsonNode.class);
        ObjectNode recordNode = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
        JsonNode examPortionNode = value.get("code_portions");
        ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) examPortionNode;

        for (int iterate = 0; iterate <= arrayNode.size() - 1; iterate++) {
            JsonNode insideArr;
            insideArr = (JsonNode) arrayNode.get(iterate);
            recordNode.put("ID", portionValue.get("id").isNull() ? null : value.get("id").asInt());
            recordNode.put("eventDateTime", portionValue.get("effective_date").isNull() ? null : value.get("effective_date").asText());
            String portionCode = insideArr.get("portion_code").asText();
            String portionName = insideArr.get("portion_name").asText();
            recordNode.put("PortionIndex", (iterate + 1));
            recordNode.put("PortionCode", portionCode);
            recordNode.put("PortionName", portionName);
            recordNode.put("systemModifiedDate", String.valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.now()));
            //System.out.println("Outout from ObjectNode = " + recordNode);
            recordsList.add(KeyValue.pair(key, recordNode));

        }
        recordsList.stream().forEach((records) -> System.out.println(records));
    }
}
```

**Program output :**

```
KeyValue(abc, {"ID":247,"eventDateTime":"2020-06-21T23:30:00Z","PortionIndex":2,"PortionCode":"1234","PortionName":"Test2","systemModifiedDate":"2021-06-12T13:57:47.551978800"})
KeyValue(abc, {"ID":247,"eventDateTime":"2020-06-21T23:30:00Z","PortionIndex":2,"PortionCode":"1234","PortionName":"Test2","systemModifiedDate":"2021-06-12T13:57:47.551978800"})
```

**Expected output :**

```
KeyValue(abc, {"ID":247,"eventDateTime":"2020-06-21T23:30:00Z","PortionIndex":1,"PortionCode":"123","PortionName":"Test1","systemModifiedDate":"2021-06-12T13:57:47.536357600"})
KeyValue(abc, {"ID":247,"eventDateTime":"2020-06-21T23:30:00Z","PortionIndex":2,"PortionCode":"1234","PortionName":"Test2","systemModifiedDate":"2021-06-12T13:57:47.551978800"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the same `recordNode` on each pass of the loop. You need to create a new one inside your loop.

Just move this piece of code inside the loop:

```
ObjectNode recordNode = new ObjectMapper().createObjectNode();
```